# curl not sending image attachment

Tags: php, file, curl, file-upload

```
$accessToken = 'ZDJjNDRlZDIwNDVhYzIxYzAyZDQxYzNkMDJmODdmZDc4MTQzYzA5MWFjOTk4NDE1MjUyZWMxYjUwMGUzNmE4ZQ';
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken);
$uploadfile="images/a.png"; 
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.abc.be/api/entranceticket/create',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'api_entrance_ticket[productName]' => 'Event1',
    'api_entrance_ticket[reference]' => 'M1-1',
    'api_entrance_ticket[description]' => 'Event1',
    'api_entrance_ticket[price]' => '5',
    'api_entrance_ticket[shop]' => 'SJK305801',
    'api_entrance_ticket[ticketWindowOpening]' => '2014-09-03 00:00:00',
    'api_entrance_ticket[ticketWindowClosing]' => '2014-09-23 23:59:00',
    'api_entrance_ticket[isNumbered]' => '1',
    'api_entrance_ticket[image]' => '@'.$uploadfile ,
    'api_entrance_ticket[sizeX]' => '10',
    'api_entrance_ticket[sizeY]' => '8'
    )

));


// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
if(!curl_exec($curl)){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);

echo $resp;
```

When using this script on the hosting of the api owner everything works.  When we use it at our hosting to send data to the api, the image is not sent.  They receive the curl call but refuse it because no image is present.

Any idea why this isn't working at our side?

Don't look at the SSL FALSE, we're connecting to a non secure test environment.

EDIT: changed to '@'.$uploadfile

Comment: Did you try the full path for image file?

Comment: Do you mean http://www.abc.be/image.png ? Or should it be something like /usr/local/...

Comment: try second one and let me now the result

Comment: I've tried with /public_html/images/a.png
Do I have to go deeper in the server.

Comment: in your case you can do `$uploadfile = __DIR__.'/images/a.png';`

Comment: Tried your info with __DIR__ but didn't work.  So I tried to remove the / before images to see if this was needed.  When removing I got the message 'Error: "couldn't open file "/home/volleyas/public_htmlimages/a.png"  which seems normal.  However when I try again based on this with 
$uploadfile='/home/volleyas/public_html/images/a.png'; the api still returns that no file is included.  However when I browse to the image in my browser, the image is shown.

Comment: and all other data is sent normally?

Comment: The api returns {"code":412,"message":"Image is required."}

Comment: did you try  `'image' => '@'.$uploadfile,` instead of ` 'api_entrance_ticket[image]' => '@'.$uploadfile ,`?

Comment: Tried but same error message

Comment: Added Print_r($curl[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]); to the script but nothing returns. Normal?